# Comoving Hubble radius in terms of expansion scale factor

Tags: cosmology, space-expansion, cosmological-inflation, space

I am currently reading Baumann's Cambridge [lecture slides](http://static.sif.it/SIF/resources/public/files/va2013/Baumann-0507.pdf) on cosmology and am confused on the notion of the Hubble radius. On page 10 it is stated that for a perfect fluid with constant equation of state $w = P/\rho$, the comoving Hubble radius is $(aH)^{-1} \propto a^{0.5(1+3w)}$, but I haven't the faintest idea where this equation came from, as no derivation is given. Can anyone provide one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Planck units, $M_P=(8\pi G)^{-1}=1$.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! However, why do we assume a flat universe in this scenario? Most of the work I have done so far has not made this assumption

Comment: @wrb98 observations suggest the universe is spatially flat